# Problems with radioButtons in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want the following radioButtons scheme in my R markdown Shiny report:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
fluidRow(
  br(),
  column(3, radioButtons("optVarPheno", "Variables", choices = c("A1", "A2", "A3"), selected = "A1")),
  column(3, radioButtons("optVarScore", "Score", choices = c("EXTENSIVE", "MODERATE", "CONTROL"), selected = "EXTENSIVE")),
  column(3, radioButtons("optVarPheno", "Group", choices = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), selected = "")),
  column(3, radioButtons("optVarScore", "Score", choices = c("HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW"), selected = ""))

)

fluidRow(
  column(12,
    renderText({

      selvar <- sprintf("%s_%s", input$optVarPheno, input$optVarScore)
      sprintf("Selected var: %s", selvar)

    })
  )
)
```
````

The behavior of the radio buttons is as expected. The 1st and 3rd columns are grouped by sharing the same Id, as well as the 2nd and 4th columns. But it only reacts when I choose from the first two columns, and I can see the text e.g. "Selected var: A1_MODERATE". If I click on elements from the 3rd and 4th columns nothing happens. The message "Selected var:" doesn't change.

What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using same name for two radio buttons, try changing names

Comment: UI elements (like `radioButtons`) shouldn't share the same id name. You don't group radio buttons by assigning them the same name.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But then, how you group them if they need to be in different columns? If I give different names, then they are not anymore mutually exclusive options.

Comment: You'll need to do some backend processing (i.e. whenever a choice is selected in column 1, any selected in column 3 becomes unselected). This can be done in the server code with `observeEvent`

Comment: Hi, can you give please some example how to do it? I was trying to use updateRadioButtons() in an observeEvent() but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: My experiment shows that, as Shiny does not really allow clearing all choices in `radioButtons`, even when you update `selected` to an empty string, the previous choice is still returned by `input$optVarScore` or `input$optVarPheno`. For example, if I initially selected `A1`, then change to `B1`, while I can make the selection of `A1` disappear from UI by updating `selected=""`, `A1` actually is still selected. If I select `A1` again, Shiny will not know that I changed my input again. In conclusion I would suggest this is not possible.